# If $T \in \mathcal{B}_{00}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{H})$, show $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{ran}(T^*))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken from Conway's A course in functional analysis chapter 2 section 4 problem 3

Problem Statement: If $T \in \mathcal{B}_{00}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{H})$, show that $T^*\in \mathcal{B}_{00}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{H})$ and $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{ran}(T^*))$.

Below is my following attempt:

We just have to show $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(T)) = \dim(\operatorname{ran}(T^*))$ and $T \in \mathcal{B}_{00}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{H})\Rightarrow T^*\in \mathcal{B}_{00}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{H})$ will follow immediately. By theorem 2.19, we know that $Ker(T) = (\operatorname{ran}(T^*))^\perp \Rightarrow \operatorname{ran}(T^*) = Ker(T)^\perp$. Similarly, $\operatorname{ran}(A) = Ker(T^*)^\perp$. By definition of the adjoint operator, we know for any $x, y \in \mathcal{H}$ we have: $\langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle x, T^*y\rangle$.

Not sure how I would finish this proof.

Comment: What is $\mathcal B_{00}$?

Comment: The set of linear operators of finite rank over a Hilbert space.

Comment: Minor notation quibble:  What great improvement is there in omitting the "k" in "rank"?  Also, \ker gives $\ker$.

Comment: 'ran' denotes 'range', and it's usual in functional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U:=(\ker T)^\perp$. We have $H=\ker T\oplus U$ and $T|_U:U\to\mathop{\rm ran}T$ is a linear isomorphism, so based on what you already have, we get
$$\dim(\mathop{\rm ran}T^*)\,=\, \dim(U)\,=\, \dim(\mathop{\rm ran}T)\,.$$